# How to make appearing text on background image, not interfere to each other and to another text?

Tags: javascript, css, animation, show-hide

I need to make an appearing text in the background-image (banner). Text sentences are in array. The script should take 7 random sentences and show it on background-image with different time of show/hide. Also when the text is hidden every time should take new random co-ordinates place to show. Appearing text shouldn't interefe to each other and other text like h1 or menu items. Sentences should appear only on the right site of the page.

```js
$(function() {
var array = ['first text', 'second sentence', 'Integer nec arcu est. In cursus', 'id tincidunt fermentum.', 'Vivamus mattis rhoncus risus', 'cursus, nec gravida nulla malesuada', 'interdum tortor, id c', 'r viverra arcu id', 'dictum eu volutpat odio', 'Curabitur viverra arcu ', ' elit. Nulla veh', 'posuere velit. Pellentesqu', 'interdum tortor,', 'Vivamus mattis rhoncus risus', 'egestas in blandit in, ultricies ac nibh', 'Vestibulum ante ipsum prim', 'lobortis orci rutrum in.', 'dum finibus. Duis sagittis', 'erat ultrices leo, vi', 'el. Suspendisse blandit mi sit', 'id cursus neque sapien', 'consectetur adipiscing elit.', 'Duis non quam ', 'quis nibh egestas,', 'non maximus luctu', 'non maximus luctu', 'Curabitur a fermentum ante', ]
});
```

```css
.banner {
    background-image: url('http://www.pswca.org/images/skins/bg-banner-blue.png');
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    height: 100vh;
}

.banner h1 {
    font-size: 40px;
    font-weight: 200;
    line-height: 80px;
    color: #000;
}

.banner-text {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
            align-items: center;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

.banner-text h1 {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: 10%;
}

.animate-text {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='banner'>
    <div class="banner-text align-self-center">
        <h1>Text text text,<br>
            <span class='text-blue'>text text</span></h1>
    </div>
            <div class="animate-text">
              <!-- here should be apearing sentences -->
              <span class='apear'></span>
              <span class='apear'></span>
              <span class='apear'></span>
              <span class='apear'></span>
              <span class='apear'></span>
              <span class='apear'></span>

            </div>
</div>
```

Sentences should appear only on the right side of the page.

1. Sentences in array.
2. Script should take 7 random sentences.
3. Script take random coordinates for sentences so that they do not collide with each other and with the static text h1.
4. Putting them on the background with different delay but the same time of the animation.
5. When the sentence disappears, the next one should be displayed in different place.

Comment: I'm confused, is only one sentence supposed to appear at a time?

Comment: 5 or 6. And their should appear in random place with random animation delay

Comment: @mat If a sentence is inserted or removed (except for the last span) the other sentences will jump horizontally. Is that the behaviour you expect?